# Word VBA causing issues in template

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word 2010 template with fields, and drop down lists etc and a save button to save the document in a certain place with a certain name.  Part of the file name I retrieve as the network username in VBA and another part of the file name is the Date.  This works fine for me but when I attempt to test the document with another user the VBA code complains at the line below stating "Compile error: can't find project or library".

```
strUserName = (Environ$("username"))
```

If I changed the above to be like the line below instead and another user opens the template and clicks the save button

```
strUserName = "validnetworkname"
```

It then complains with the same error at the next VBA referencing which is

```
strDate = Date
```

What is wrong here please?

Answer (score 0):

I use this function:

```
Private Declare Function apiGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
Public Function UserName() As String
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim lnglen As Long
        lnglen = 255

    Dim strSpace As String
        strSpace = String(254, 0)

    Dim lngX As Long
        lngX = apiGetUserName(strSpace, lnglen)

    If lngX <> 0 Then GetUserName = Left(strSpace, lnglen - 1)

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ErrProc:
    Resume Leave
End Function
```

To call it:

```
Dim user_ As String
    user_ = UserName
```

Comment: @kostats K.  Thanks but it is looking like it could be the entire VBA "reference" that is the problem.  What I did was I commented out the strUserName = (Environ$("username")) and made it strUserName = "valid network name" and when another user opens the document and clicks save it gives the same error at the next line that references a VBA object which is strDate = Date.  I will update my post with this information. Any ideas please?

Comment: Seems like there's no access to Visual Basic for Applications. See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt6cbe57.aspx

Comment: Thanks Kostas.  Yes it seems like anyone else using this has no access to any of the VBA components.  I followed the link but I am using Word 2010 and had to go File >> Options >> Trust Center.  Here there was no options under the "Security & more" section  and in the "Microsoft Word Trust Center" section I selected "Trust Center Settings" and in Macro Settings I selected "Enable all macros" and checked the box for "Trust access to the VBA project object model".  But the outcome was the same.  Does each user have to change their settings or just me?  The template is saved as a .docm!